# React: Re-render component when prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Why child component displays updated prop value **only** when I'm using useState?

**For example:**

- It works when I'm calling `setReRender()` with any random values.

#### Parent Component (demo code):

```react
import Child from './Child';
const Parent = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
    const [reRender, setReRender] = useState(" ");
    return (
        <>
            {arr.map(client => {
                return(
                    <Child
                        setReRender={setReRender}
                        arr={arr}
                        firstName={client.firstName}
                        lastName={client.lastName}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </>
    )
}
```

- The update will be displayed on the screen only after I'm calling `setReRender()`.
- For example- it works with `setReRender(Math.random() * 2)`.

`useEffect` supposed to listen for update or change etc. but I didn't know that it will work with `useState`.

Is this the right way to make the parent component re-render itself?

#### Edit:

Apologies if my question isn't clear enough, it's my first time here.

Comment: Please show the code in your Child component

Comment: What update are you referring to? If you ignore the hack setRerender, what prop change are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I appreciate your comments, thank you. You can see my comment to @ utsavojha95 where I'm describing what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The component re-renders automatically if there is a change in state, so when you are calling it with random values you are changing the state of the component and it is being re-rendered

Can you describe what your program is trying to do?

Comment: You pretty much answered my question, thank you.
The program displays vacations.
Users can like and unlike each vacation displayed.
The parent component fetches vacations from the database using useEffect, the child component represents each vacation through cards, styled using CSS.
The child component receives from the parent component the 'vacation Array' through the prop.
I want to display for users the "Like" and "Unlike" icons respectively and the number of likes for each vacation. So I manipulate the array on the child component in order to display the correct results on the screen.

Comment: Thats nice no problem, in the future try adding more of your code and maybe link to it using an online ide, so you can get better answers, if thats what you want.